# Jackson - Cannot deserialize list of strings

Tags: java, jackson

On both sides I have:

```
Class ListWrapper {
    public List<String> l;
    ListWrapper(List<String> l) {
        this.l = l;
    }
}
```

On the client side I have:

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String fl;
    try {
        fl = mapper.writeValueAsString(new ListWrapper(u.getList()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        fl = "null";
    }
```

On the server side I have:

```
String data = getQuery().........;
List l = new ObjectMapper.readValue(data,ListWrapper.class).list;
```

Yet I'm getting:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not create Bean deserializer for ([simple type, class il.ac.technion.ssdl.hitch.resource.ListWrapper]): neither default/delegating constructor nor factory methods found
```

When I'm trying to deserialize the list.

EDIT:

When printing the list on the client side I'm getting:

```
 {"list":["v1","v2,"v3"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> default/delegating constructor nor factory methods found

Probably your `ListWrapper` class is missing a default constructor.

```
public ListWrapper(){
}
```

You JSON string is incorrect:

> {"list":["v1","v2,"v3"]} <<<---  double quotes missing after v2 !

Comment: Added on both sides but no change.

Comment: I think so. I added it to the post.